# simple jQuery doesn't work on server (but locally)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a simple HTML page

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Home </title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="_includes/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_includes/readAboutXML_OLD.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="content"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ loadXML("page1"); }); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and my readAboutXML_OLD.js file

```
function loadXML(whichPage) {

    $.get("_includes/about.xml",{   },function(xml){
        $("#content").append($(whichPage,xml).find("content").html());
    });
}
```

the jquery.js is version 1.3.2 and all works fine on my local machine. 
but when I upload it to a server, FF error console says "Error:this[0].innerHTML is undefined" (then points to my sourcefile).

Can anyone enlighten me?? again, the file works find locally, XML gets displayed and all is good.  oh, here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<about>

  <page1>
        <imageTag>about/ProgramOverview.jpg</imageTag>
        <headline>Program Overview</headline>
        <content>
<p><strong>Unparalleled Learning and Networking Opportunities</strong></p>
     <p>Financial support is a critical component of the Program............</p></content>
        <captionText>Scholar</captionText>
        <captionBkgd>about/ProgramOverviewCaptionBkgd.jpg</captionBkgd>
  </page1> 
</about>
```

Comment: try using the google api for accessing jquery...'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'

Answer (score 0):

- Are you transporting it from a non-case sensitive OS to a case sensitive OS (like Windows to UNIX).. If so check the name on your file exactly matches.
- Is the security correct on your Includes directory to allow reads by the web server service?

Just stuff to check